# How to do a simple addslash to a string c#

Tags: c#, string, replace, addslashes

I would like to do a simple addslash to a string in c#.

My string is (for example) : 
"bla bla ' bla bla"
And i would like the new string to be : 
"bla bla \' bla bla".

Unfortunately, when i do

```
str.Replace("'", "\'") or str.Replace("'", "\\'")
```

or a lot of other combination i end up with :

"bla bla \\' bla bla". I don't get it to just have one backslash.

Do you guys have some ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems you are getting what you want. Check your question, I think there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: you might want to check your post, because what you want to achieve is what you have already achieved, so there must be a typo somewhere. (ninj'd by nunespascal)

Comment: I wonder whatz the question here ! !

Comment: Apparently two slashes in markdown only appear as a sinlge slash, too.

Answer (score 6):

`str.Replace("'", "\\'")` is the correct usage. It will replace a single quote with a single slash followed by a single quote.

Due to the way that strings are displayed in the C# debugger, if will look like *two* slashes, but if you display the string somewhere (console, web page, winform, file output) it will only have one slash.

Comment: Alternatively, `str.Replace("'", @"\'");` for less / more confusion.

Comment: You understood the problem he was facing real quick. Nice!